# Math Expressions

Tags: mathematics, reading-aloud

I don't know how to read most of the math expressions.

For example:

- 2/6
- 7<sup>5</sup>

Is there anything to learn them?

Comment: [This](http://www.uefap.com/speaking/symbols/symbols.htm) can be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In U.S. English:

> 2/6

This can be read many different ways.  A few common ones:

1. *"Two over six"*  Emphasizing that is a fraction.
2. *"Two sixths"*  Again emphasizing that it is a fraction - specifically a number of *sixths.*
3. *"Two divided by six"* Calling out that relationship between fractions and division.
4. *"six into two"* A short form of the above, used more frequently when the numerator is larger than the denominator.  (e.g. 13/2 = 6.5  *Two into thirteen is six point five* )
5. *"Two out of six"*  If the statement is about ratios.  *"Two out of six doctors drink soy sauce."*
6. *"Two of six"* short form of #5  *"Two of six doctors drink soy sauce."*
7. *"Two per six"* similar to #5, especially in describing a success rate. *"My answers were accepted at a rate of about two per six."*

> 7<sup>5</sup>

This is an easier one, because it really has only one meaning, albeit with different ways of pronouncing it.  Here are some common ones.

"*The fifth power of seven"*

*"Seven raised to the fifth power"* OR *"Seven raised to the fifth"*

*"Seven to the fifth power"* OR *"Seven to the fifth"*   OR *"seven to the power of five"*

The last two are handy when you are raising a value to something less compact than *5*.

*7<sup>3x+1</sup>*  is *"Seven to the power of three ex plus one."* or *"seven to the three ex plus one"*

Comment: Superficially related: Page numbers are often given in this format, where the "numerator" is the current page, and the "denominator" is the total number of pages in the book/chapter/leaflet/document.  In that case, we might use the ordinal.  _"2/6 --> Second page of six."_